# Get Text and post to an included file

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do:

I have two files: One is the **header.php** which is included (*by php include*) into my second file **content.php**

> *I am going to be use my **header.php** with many different 'content' files, just so you know*

Now, I have a *div* that is going to display a title text provided by **content.php** and any other pages that includes the **header.php**:  `<div class="title"> </div>` This *div* is **only** in the **header.php**.

My problem is that I do not know how to include a text into the **header.php div area** `<div class="title"> </div>` from my **content.php** which again includes the **header.php**.

1. **Header.php** (contains the `<div class="title"></div>`)
2. **Content.php** (needs to have the title text and be included into the **header.php** `<div class="title"> <div>` area)

My question is: **How in heck can I do this with php?**

And I am not very knowledgeable about php or any type of coding for that matter. I have just been winging it, now I'm rather stuck. So If anyone could possibly explain how to do this in a simplified way, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic simple system would work like this:

header.php:

```
<div class="title"><?php if (isset($title)) { echo $title; } ?></div>
```

content.php:

```
<?php
$title = 'This is my content page';
?>
blah blah blah html here.
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
blah blah more html her e
```

header.php would check for the presence of a "title" variable, and output it if need be. If there's no title varaible, you get an empty div.

The content page is responsible for setting the title variable. And when the header page is included, it'll be in the same "scope" as the content.php code, pick up the variable, and run with it.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. (^w ^) Thank you for explaining it to me too.